Complicated triple sum in pandas dataframe
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "Race_ID": [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5],
  "Student_ID": [3,5,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,7,2,3,9,10,2,3,6,5],
  "theta": [3,4,6,8,9,2,12,4,9,0,6,5,2,5,30,3,2,1,50]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

and I would like to create a new column df['feature'] by the following method: with each Race_ID, suppose the Student_ID is equal to $i$, then we define feature to be
$$\sum_{k=\not= i}\sum_{j\not= i,k} f(k,j,i), \ \ f(k,j,i):=\frac{\theta_j+\theta_i}{\theta_i+\theta_j+\theta_k\cdot \theta_i}$$,
where $k,j$ are the Student_IDs within the same Race_ID and $theta_i$ is theta with Student_ID equals to i. So for example for Race_ID $=1$, we have
feature for Student_ID $= 3$: $f(5,4,3)+f(4,5,3)=124/175=0.708577$
feature for Student_ID $= 5$: $f(3,4,5)+f(4,3,5)=232/341=0.680352$
feature for Student_ID $= 4$: $f(3,5,4)+f(5,3,4)=97/154=0.629870$
Here is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work and also seems to be very slow when the dataframe is large:
def compute_sum(row, df):
  Race_ID = row['Race_ID']
  n_RaceID = df.groupby('Race_ID')['Student_ID'].nunique()[Race_ID]
  theta_i_values = df[(df['Race_ID'] == Race_ID) & (df['Student_ID'] == row['Student_ID'])]['theta'].values
  theta_values = df[(df['Race_ID'] == Race_ID) & (df['Student_ID'] != row['Student_ID'])]['theta'].values
  sum_ = sum([((theta_values[j] + theta_i_values[i]) / (theta_i_values[i] + theta_values[j] + theta_values[k] * theta_i_values[i])) for i in range(len(theta_i_values)) for k in range(len(theta_values)) if k != i for j in range(len(theta_values)) if j != i and j != k])
  return sum_

df['feature'] = df.apply(lambda row: compute_sum(row, df), axis=1)


Please double check your computations, they seem incorrect for students 5 and 4. One major issue in your approach is that you can have the same student id across different race id and they have different theta.

One option could be to create a function to operate per group with groupby.apply, a set of the student ids and itertools.permutations:
from itertools import permutations

def f(tk, tj, ti):
    return (tj+ti)/(tj+ti+tk*ti)

def compute(g):
    thetas = dict(zip(g['Student_ID'], g['theta']))
    ids = set(g['Student_ID'])
    
    return pd.Series((sum(f(thetas[k], thetas[j], thetas[i])
                             for (k,j) in permutations(S, 2))
                      for i in g['Student_ID'] for S in [ids-{i}]),
                     index=g.index)

df['feature'] = (df.groupby('Race_ID', group_keys=False)
                   .apply(compute, include_groups=False)
                )

Output:
    Race_ID  Student_ID  theta    feature
0         1           3      3   0.708571
1         1           5      4   0.680352
2         1           4      6   0.629870
3         2           1      8   3.307021
4         2           2      9   3.213902
5         2           3      2   4.770714
6         2           4     12   2.995137
7         2           5      4   3.890607
8         3           4      9   1.142857
9         3           3      0   2.000000
10        3           7      6   1.100000
11        4           2      5   0.000000
12        4           3      2   0.000000
13        5           9      5   8.129834
14        5          10     30   6.170815
15        5           2      3   8.695333
16        5           3      2   9.249267
17        5           6      1  10.557860
18        5           5     50   5.669121


thank you so much! Just checked my computation, it was wrong, updated, many thanks for your help!

My Solution
import pandas as pd
# Given DataFrame
data = {
  "Race_ID": [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5],
  "Student_ID": [3,5,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,7,2,3,9,10,2,3,6,5],
  "theta": [3,4,6,8,9,2,12,4,9,0,6,5,2,5,30,3,2,1,50]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to calculate the feature
def calculate_feature(row):
    race_id = row['Race_ID']
    student_id = row['Student_ID']
    theta_i = row['theta']
    
    race_data = df[df['Race_ID'] == race_id]
    feature_sum = 0
    
    for index, data in race_data.iterrows():
        if data['Student_ID'] != student_id:
            theta_j = data['theta']
            for index2, data2 in race_data.iterrows():
                if data2['Student_ID'] != student_id and data2['Student_ID'] != data['Student_ID']:
                    theta_k = data2['theta']
                    feature_sum += (theta_j + theta_i) / (theta_i + theta_j + (theta_k * theta_i))
    
    return feature_sum

# Applying the function to create the new column 'feature'
df['feature'] = df.apply(calculate_feature, axis=1)

# Displaying the updated DataFrame
print(df)

